# jQuery - wait until confirmation popup returns value

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

So I have a table of records, where everyone of them has a remove button. I want to add a confirmation popup, which will shows up when button clicked.

```
 var $confirmDialog = $('<div></div>')
    .html('This record will be removed.')
    .dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Remove confirtmation',
    buttons: {
      "OK": function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
        return true;
      },
      "Cancel": function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
```

My remove button event:

```
$(".removeButton").on("click", function(){
    if($confirmDialog.dialog('open')){
       var name =  $(this).siblings(".someClassForNameHolder").text();
       var urlPath = $("#hiddenForUrl").val();
       Application.postRecord(name, "Remove", urlPath); 
    }
});
```

Btw, i have few following points:

1) I can't provide every record in the table with unique ids, so I have to keep my data collections (`name` variable) inside my `removeButton` event (to be able to use this.sibling...).

2) I want my script to wait until `$confirmDialog` returns value and only then continue code execution.

Comment: What about `Application.postRecord(name, "Remove", urlPath, function(data){ /*data.id*/ }); `

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i don't really understand what 'function(data){ /*data.id*/ }' should do. Is it popup call?

Comment: Never mind :) I'm not clear what are you asking

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i was asking if it is able to stop my script from executing until i get my return value from pop or transfer parameters into popup, OK-button event.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign your `urlPath` to a global variable, and execute the `POST` inside the `OK` handler:

```
var nameToRemove, urlPathToRemove;

var $confirmDialog = $('<div></div>')
    .html('This record will be removed.')
    .dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Remove confirtmation',
    buttons: {
      "OK": function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
        Application.postRecord(nameToRemove, "Remove", urlPathToRemove); 
      },
      "Cancel": function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
        return false;
      }
    }
  });

  $(".removeButton").on("click", function(){
    if($confirmDialog.dialog('open')){
       nameToRemove =  $(this).siblings(".someClassForNameHolder").text();
       urlPathToRemove= $("#hiddenForUrl").val();
    }
  });
```

Comment: I thought about using global variables, and it probably will work, however it would be great to avoid it and keep everything inside my event. I was wondering if i can use something like `delay(tillExpression == true)`

Comment: A better way (and this is what I usually do) is to create a form with your hidden fields in it (`name` in this case), and dynamically set the action of that form to your url (when an item is clicked). Make that form be your popup confirmation. So it will be hidden by default. Then, just make the `Confirm` button be the submit button on that form. Of course, then you would not use your dialog function. It's quite a bit different from the mechanism you are using now, which is why I didn't suggest it.

Comment: yeap, i would like to keep my ajax-post, however idea with hiddens is decent. I can assign them with values, call my popup and then collect them again by ids in OK-button event. For now i think it is the best solution.